# I created an ndb.model with a duplicated property name

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have an NDB Model class in Python on App Engine.

I just noticed my model's class definition has repeated a property definition.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Account(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    started = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=False)
    #...    
    started = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=False)
```

The bug's been there for a while and never caused an issue while creating objects and saving or reading the *started* property.

Now if I delete one of the copies, then the model won't align with what is was stored in the datastore.

What is the correct way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `started` and you are all set. Only one (second) property is actually saved in datastore, you can check this in datastore entities tab

Comment: Are you sure? I tried that, and my model started to behave poorly - updates to the property on older objects were not stored. I ended up deleting the old objects so I couldn't confirm what was askew.

Comment: Do you mean updates of `started` property? `auto_now` should be set to True to update on each put/update

Comment: The property was set manually. However, it seemed to be returning its old value not the updated one which is why I asked the question. Otherwise, the behaviour you described is exactly how I would expect it to work.